# Why is Flask-Cors not detecting my Cross-Origin domain in production?

Tags: docker, flask, cors, webserver, flask-cors

My website has a separate server for the front-end and back-end, and so my back-end server needs to open up CORS permissions so that the front-end can request data from it.

I am using [Flask-Cors](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html) **successfully** in development, but it doesn't work when I deploy to production.  *(please note that I have looked at other flask-cors questions on SO, but none of them fit my situation)*

Here is the relevant code that is **working** in development:

```
# 3rd party imports
import flask
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, send_from_directory, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

# Create the app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=[
  'http://localhost:5001',
])

# Define the routes
@app.route('/')
def index():
  # no CORS code was necessary here
  app.logger.info(f'request is: {flask.request}')
```

What I've tried:

- Adding my server's ip address `'http://162.243.168.182:5001'` to the CORS list is **not** enough to resolve the issue, although I understand it should be there.
- It seems that using `'*'` to allow ALL origins does **not** work either.  (very suspicious!)

Please note that I am using a Docker container, so my environment between development and prod are almost identical.  But what's different is that I'm on a different server and I've modified the front-end to send the request to the new IP address (resulting in the famous `“Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header missing` CORS error).

Now I'm wondering if the `flask.request` object is somehow missing information, and this causes Flask-Cors to not send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header like it's supposed to.  I can provide that logging info if you think it would help!

### More information!

The Dockerfile I am using in PROD is:

```
# base image
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8-2020-12-19

# install deps
RUN pip3 install ediblepickle==1.1.3
# RUN pip3 install flask==1.1.2 # pre-installed on tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask
RUN pip3 install flask-cors==3.0.9
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.19.2
RUN pip3 install scipy==1.5.2
RUN pip3 install pandas==1.1.2
RUN pip3 install networkx==2.5

# pull in files for deployment
COPY ./app /app

# Note that there is no CMD to run because the CMD set in the base image is what we already wanted.  As long as the Flask app is called `app`, the python file is named `main.py`, the parent directory is named `app`, and that same directory gets copied into `/app`, then the base image is designed to make our app work out-of-the-box.
```

and the command I use to kick it off is:

```
docker build -t mvlancellotti/tennis-backend:prod -f prod.Dockerfile . && docker run --rm -p 5000:80 --name tennis-backend-container mvlancellotti/tennis-backend:prod
```

Going into the `/app` directory of the container, there is the file `uwsgi.ini` with contents:

```
[uwsgi]
module = main
callable = app
```

which seems to work, and the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has contents:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
```

and the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` has contents:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your nginx/apache config look like?

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Please see `nginx.conf` which I have now added above.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker I have now added a SECOND `nginx.conf` file above.  I don't know why there are two.

Answer (score 7):

The thing is, it is the server you are requesting resources ***from*** should have the CORS header (let it be `serverA`), not the server which requires remote files (`serverB`). If `serverA` is `NGINX` or `Apache2` you can use this to add CORS header to responses:

**NGINX**:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
# or
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin serverB;
```

**Apache2**:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# or
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "serverB"
```

This above means *"allow * or serverB to fetch resources from this server (serverA)"*.

For anyone new to CORS I recommend these two ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)) short readings from Mozilla. I think they are great at explaining the basics.

Comment: I have added `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` to my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` file, but the same CORS error persists: _Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/?gender=m&stat=ace&normalization=percent&reverse=false&limit=5. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)._

Comment: Please also take a look at the extra info I have included above.

Comment: @mareoraft Where have you put that line? Judging by the config you should have placed it either in `location @app` or `location /`. Or both, if an initial request may end up in both places. Also remember to restart or reload NGINX after making changes.

Comment: I had put that line in the `location /` block, and now I have put it in both, but the error persists.  I am in fact modifying the file _before_ kicking the server off with `exec /usr/bin/supervisord` which apparently starts Supervisor, "with Nginx and uWSGI".

Comment: Why are we convinced that **nginx** is the only issue here?  What logging / troubleshooting steps can we take to see if nginx is receiving and blocking the request?  It's very suspicious that the error message the browser gives says `localhost` instead of `162.243.168.182`.  Let me see if the frontend is using the correct url...

Comment: Okay so we have progress...  I fixed the frontend URL and now the error complains that there are TOO MANY Cors headers :D.  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:5001` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: Removing the **nginx** config changes gets it to work.  Both frontend and backend docker containers are on the same server (and same IP address), but they are separate containers.  Does this mean I no longer need `CORS` support in my Flask app at all?  I added it during development because it was necessary, but perhaps it is not needed in PROD.  Of course I can't use `*` in prod because it is insecure.

Comment: @mareoraft You do not need CORS when you have everything on the same origin (domain or IP-address) because it is not cross-origin anymore. The problem you faced was either bad header or no header (you could have checked response headers with dev tools in browser).  My answer isn't fully correct here but now you probably can agree that setting up a web server to handle CORS is easier than flask. IMO CORS in  flask might be handy when extra origins are changing constantly. In this example scenario you could benefit from flask by generating header value using a database or something like that.

Comment: @mareoraft I guess I'll update the answer for anyone else who can get into this.

Comment: Thanks again!  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Kindly, You need to consider several things in your production environment.
First of all, please share your docker-related configurations ( Dockerfile, Docker-Compose if you have ) because you are trying to fix the issue somewhere that is not related to the root cause. for example, if you are using **Apache** or **Nginx** to serve HTTP requests as reverse_proxy, so you need to add related headers into their configuration. But I suggest you use the following codes, previously I faced some issue like you, and the following code resolved mine :

```py
cors = CORS(flask_app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*", "allow_headers": "*", "expose_headers": "*"}})
```

**Update: adding Nginx config**

Here is the Most Complete & Wide-Open CORS configuration for Nginx:

**Nginx Config Complete CORS Open**

For some of the configurations, Wildcard ( * sign ) is not supported by some old browsers, So, I've added a list of somehow all possible values, but you need to modify it based on your application requirements and policies. Also, you can move the "add_headers" part to any location of your config file that needs to be there.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'CONNECT, DEBUG, DELETE, DONE, GET, HEAD, HTTP, HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, OPTIONS, ORIGIN, ORIGINS, PATCH, POST, PUT, QUIC, REST, SESSION, SHOULD, SPDY, TRACE, TRACK';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With';


    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

**Nginx Simpler CORS Config File**

Also, you can use the following code, but maybe you face some cors errors that you can solve quickly by comparing with the previous sample. most of the time there is some header in the response which is not **allowed** and **exposed** in the lists.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,Access-Control-Expose-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Expose-Headers';
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,Access-Control-Expose-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Expose-Headers'
```

You can also check out this link for more detail on CORS. [Link](https://geekflare.com/enable-cors-apache-nginx/)

Comment: I used your suggested line (modifying `/api/` to the appropriate path), but I still obtain the CORS error.

Comment: Please see the additional information I have added to the question.

Comment: @mareoraft, use the /api/v1/ for version management of your APIs, it would be useful if you provide APIs for some mobile applications. you can release your new major APIs on /v2/ and keep the old APIs on /v1/ backward compatible. 

but the point was for other parameters like expose headers and .. in my python codes, please check them out.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to take a look tomorrow.  My issue is not yet resolved but I am getting close.

Comment: Thanks again, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to add a comment, but still not enough rep..

Nginx [add_header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) won't work for error codes.

Also when you receive any kind of error (400, 500, 502, etc) the header will be missing. And the browser will show you CORS, but nevermind, something went wrong elsewhere.
It's common to lose a lot of time because of this...

I accessed your app (sorry if it's not mentioned to do so). It loads and some filter options results in 502 and browser will say: Oh, CORS!
But looks like something is dying and coming back.

Info regarding add_header and errors: https://serverfault.com/questions/431274/nginx-services-fails-for-cross-domain-requests-if-the-service-returns-error

Comment: From the link you've mentioned `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;` overcomes the problem with error codes. PS: have some rep from me :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was from the preflight test. To solve it, simply return if not a preflight request as shown below:

```
@app.before_request
def global_authenticate():
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if not token:
        # Handle case where there's no token provided
        # Return a response only if it's not a preflight request
        if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            return jsonify({'error': 'Token is missing'}) # Unauthorized status code
```